# custom rails has_many association ( through pg array )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So basically I'd like to know if there's some common approach to define own association types.
Some details:

I have a model `conversations` that has a PG array column `user_ids`.
So, to retrieve user conversations I need to run:
`select conversations.* from conversations where USER_ID = ANY(conversations.user_ids)`

Since `finder_sql` and it's friends are deprecated now, I would really like to know what would be the best way to implement this pseudo has_many association?

currently I just use the methods like:

```
 def conversations
   Conversation.where("#{id} = ANY (conversations.users)")
 end
```

So basically I'm thinking of implementing my own `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionAssociation` and would like to know if there're some good references or if you could advice where to start at

---

Comment: Do you have any control over the schema?  I ask because using an array to hold foreign keys is bad practice, and not just because of the troubles it's causing you now.  The _only_ time you should consider using an array is when it can always be treated by the database as an indivisible thing with no meaning to it.

Comment: right, I decided to go with this approach just for the sake of educational purposes. Besides, I've been absolutely amazed with arrays performance. Another things that convinced me was this one: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-9-3-development-array-element-foreign-keys/, which made me think it's not such a bad idea after all

Comment: since you decide to go with ARRAY maybe you can also go with SQL Views? https://github.com/thoughtbot/scenic And basically create another table which denormalizes your array into something like: (conversation_id, user_id) (many-many) so you can use normal has many relations.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to normalize your model to have another table who keeps the relations between users and conversations for example, building a model like

UsersConversation

and your relations will be

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users_conversations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :conversations, :through => :users_conversations
end

class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users_conversations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :users_conversations
end
```

Then you can easily do

```
#users for each specific conversation
@users = Conversation.find(1).users
#conversations for each specific user
@conversations = User.find(1).conversations
```

Unless you want to keep the same way or array, you can do it like

```
@users = User.where(:id => Conversation.find(1).user_ids)
```

if the user_ids stored as array like [1,10,20]
So, it will work fine and return the users

Answer (score 1):

You should re-structure it to the reference table where it holds the conversation_id and user_id, then you can use it the best practice from Rails (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

If you still want to keep this structure I suggest:

`User.where(id: conversion.user_ids)` (conversion is an instance of the Conversation table)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Conversation.user.select{ |conversation| conversation.user_ids.include?(params[:id])
```

Considering that user_ids column is serialized and the current user id is passed by params[:id]

The main approach is that, if you have an array you can check if it have 'something' inside with .include?(something) method. Thinking this way, you can use select method to actually select the objects (users, in this case) that have its IDs inside this array with the include method. Am I being clear?

Tell me if it worked...